# Javascript Return Console NaN

Tags: return

```
function numberOfBalls (black, white) {
return black + white;
};

function costOfBalls (black, white) {
return 100 * numberOfBalls;
};

const totalBallCost = costOfBalls(10, 20);
console.log(totalBallCost)
```

Hello, Javascript newb here. The code above keeps logging NaN to the console; I can't
see what I'm doing wrong ... could anyone help ? I've tried it multiple consoles, I've tried changing the parameters & the function names while nothing seems to help.

Comment: `100 * numberOfBalls` - what is the value of `numberOfBalls`? You probably meant to write: `return 100 * numberOfBalls(black, white);`

Comment: Yes, sincere thanks my friend, the issue has been solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You miss function call at the position numberOfBalls
Use next code:

```
function numberOfBalls (black, white) {
return black + white;
};

function costOfBalls (black, white) {
return 100 * numberOfBalls(black, white);
};

const totalBallCost = costOfBalls(10, 20);
console.log(totalBallCost)
```